# How to create window and find mode for created window in pandas(Aggregate, window and finding mode)

Tags: statistics, pandas-groupby, window-functions

I have data frame(df) like this:

```
cpt     units
36430   2
36440   5
36450   10
36430   1
36440   5
36450   10
36430   2
36440   6
36450   11
```

I need to add new column(called- mode) to above dataframe after aggregating on column(CPT), windowing and finding mode on column(units). I mean, I expect to see like this:

```
cpt units   mode
36430   2   2
36440   5   5
36450   10  10
36430   1   2
36440   5   5
36450   10  10
36430   2   2
36440   6   5
36450   11  10
```

I have tried with following code

```
df['mode'] = df.groupby(['cpt'])['units'].transform(lambda x: x.mode)
df['mode'] = df.groupby(['cpt'])['units'].transform(lambda x: x.mode())
from scipy.stats import mode
df['mode'] = df.groupby(['cpt'])['units'].transform(lambda x: mode(x))
```

No code is working as per my requirement though I am very near to my result. And I felt that on surfing internet, no direct command is there to solve my problem. Please help me out with code. THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Looking forward for the solution. Thanks..

Comment: Looking forward for the solution. Thanks.